# Who to Read Pdf etc file From Mobile Storage in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to Read PDf or etc file docoments contents from mobile storage in xamarin android

```
Intent intentPDF = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intentPDF.SetType("application/pdf");
intentPDF.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
StartActivityForResult(intentPDF, 2);
```

its open the Gallery and give the option for select PDF file.The issue is i want to read the select file content but i didn't know how to Archive this solution anyone can solve this problem?

Note:
If anyone have better solution then they can suggest me the solution.

Comment: I want to read the Contents of Selected File

Comment: you could get the path of your select file,and call back in onActivityResult method,then you could  use 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); to open it